# The output from my C++ OpenCV Hough Circle Detection and from my Python OpenCV Hough Circle Detection is different

Tags: python, c++, opencv, hough-transform

So I have copied the same folder into two different machines, one where I run OpenCV on Python and my machine, where I run OpenCV on C++. I am actually converting the Python code to C++ and I have run into this singular problem where the output from the Hough Circle detector is not the same.

Output from C++ :

```
Radius min = 752
Radius max = 846
Total number of circles detected = 3
Circle - x: 1325.5  y: 1094.5 Radius: 759.537
Circle - x: 877.5  y: 1077.5 Radius: 790.734
Circle - x: 896.5  y: 512.5 Radius: 806.832
```

Output from Python:

```
Rmin = 752
Rmax = 846
[[[1326.5        1075.5           752.5333...]
  [896.5          512.5           806.8323...]
  [877.5         1077.5           790.7341...]]]
```

C++ Source:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#define IMAGE_ROW 1882
struct O_HC{
    //return types known
    int circle[3];
    int circlesExist;
}outHC;
int main(string FILENAME)
{

    //something 
    Mat RGBimg = imread(FILENAME, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    //something something
    if(! RGBimg.data)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not load image" << std::endl; 
    }
    else
    {
        /*
        //THIS PIECE OF CODE SHOWS THE IMAGE IN A WINDOW
        namedWindow("DisplayWindow", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("DisplayWindow", RGBimg);
        waitKey(0);
        */

        //Code not involving RGBimg 
        outHC = houghcircles(RGBimg); 

    }
    return 0;

}

O_HC houghcircles(Mat RGBimg)
{
    vector<Vec3f> circles;

    cvtColor(RGBimg, GrayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    Size size(t_cols * IMAGE_ROW / t_rows, IMAGE_ROW);
    resize(GrayImg, ResizedImg, size);

    std::cout << "t_cols : " << ResizedImg.cols << std::endl;
    std::cout << "t_rows : " << ResizedImg.rows << std::endl;
    t_rows = ResizedImg.rows;
    t_cols = ResizedImg.cols;

    medianBlur(ResizedImg, BlurredImg, 5);
    black_circle_radius_low = (int) (0.4 * std::min(t_rows,t_cols));
    black_circle_radius_upper = (int) (0.45 * std::min(t_rows,t_cols));

    std::cout << "Radius min = " << black_circle_radius_low << '\n';
    std::cout << "Radius max = " << black_circle_radius_upper << '\n';

    HoughCircles(BlurredImg, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 300, 30, 30, black_circle_radius_low, black_circle_radius_upper);

    std::cout << "Total number of circles detected = " << circles.size() << std::endl;

    if(circles.size() == 0)
    {
         outHC.circlesExist = 0;
         outHC.circle[0] = 0;
         outHC.circle[1] = 0;
         outHC.circle[2] = 0;
    }
    else
    {
         outHC.circlesExist = 1;
         for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
         {
            std::cout << "Circle - x: " << circles[i][0] << "  y: " << circles[i][1] << " Radius: " << circles[i][2] << '\n';
              //Something else
         }
         outHC.circle[0] = (int)circles[0][0];
         outHC.circle[1] = (int)circles[0][1];
         outHC.circle[2] = (int)circles[0][2];
   }
   return outHC; 
}
```

Code for Python :

```
    import cv2
    import cv2.cv as cv
    IMAGE_ROW = 1882
    img = cv2.imread(filename, 0)    
    [t_rows,t_cols]= img.shape
    img = cv2.resize(img, (t_cols*IMAGE_ROW/t_rows,IMAGE_ROW))
    img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)

    [t_rows,t_cols]=img.shape        
    limit=min(t_rows,t_cols)
    black_circle_radius_low=int(0.4*limit)
    black_circle_radius_upper=int(0.45*limit)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,300,param1=30,param2=30,minRadius=black_circle_radius_low,maxRadius=black_circle_radius_upper)
    print circles
```

As we can see, the first circle is different for the different languages. Does anyone here know why this is happening?

Cheers.

PS: **OpenCV 2.4.11** is installed with Python and **OpenCV 2.4.13** is installed with C++. If it matters, the Python version is running on an Win7 machine and the C++ version is on OS X Yosemite. I am not that well versed in Python, so there may be some syntactical mistakes here and there.

[image: Picture Used - May have been compressed during upload to imgur]

edits:

Added some more code to show image reads.

Comment: Is it possible that they are linking to different libraries compiled with different SIMD intrinsics?

Comment: @cjhanks Well they are on different machines on two different platforms - the Python one is on Windows and C++ one is on OSX. But if that's the case isn't it a bit unlikely that the other circles are the same?

Comment: Maybe.  My experience is different implementations of the same algorithm can introduce subtle differences in the solution, and different architectures can also give subtly different solutions.  Resulting from rounding logic or different order of computation... or even simple bugs.

Comment: You call the one image 'img' and the other 'BlurredImg', but I assume they are the same?

Comment: @O.O. They are the same. I have added some more lines of code. The only difference I can see is that one of the C++ version passes the RGB image matrix into the function, whereas the Python version passes the filename into the function and re-reads the image as a grayscale.

Comment: @cjhanks Yeah. But why would 2 circles stay exactly the same but one change so much? Literally makes no sense.

Comment: @Roy2511 Can you please complete the C++ example (the reading part is missing) so that others can compile it and  try reproduce your issue? Same with Python imports missing. The code should run without modifications. Attach your test image. Finally, specify the versions of opencv libraries you're using (both the Python and C++ variants).

Comment: @DanMašek revising the question and uploading the photo in about two to three hours. Hope you guys stick around. :)

Comment: @DanMašek updated questions with suggested revisions

Comment: @Roy2511 The version discrepancy looks suspicious. I'd try upgrading the Python library to 2.4.13. You should be able to fetch it from the OpenCV site.

Comment: @DanMašek A version discrepancy would hurt just one circle out of three?

Comment: @Roy2511 Downloading a (self-extracting) archive and extracting a single file from it seems like the simplest way to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125046/discussion-between-roy2511-and-dan-masek).